# Convergence of series and disk or convergence

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I applied the Ratio Test and I got

$$x + 2y < 1$$

Shouldn't this give me a half plane? The answer says it is (D). The only reason why I think it could be (D) is because $y$ could be positive or negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is $|x+2y|<1$ or $x+2y=-1$: this last option gives the alternated harmonic series. Note that $$ax+by+c<0$$ is the half "plane" determined by a line, and $ax+bx+c=0$ is a line.

Comment: Where did you get $x + 2y = -1$ from?

Comment: @sizz Read my answer again, please. Or put $z=-1$ in $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}n $$ and show it converges.

Comment: What does the alternating harmonic series have to do with this?

Comment: @sizz Did you know $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$ converges?

Comment: Yes, we could verify it through the alternating series test.

Comment: @sizz Good, so the points such that $x+2y=-1$ should also be taken into account.

Comment: Oh wait I see what you are doing now. Basically you used the fact that the alt harmonic series converges, so you substituted $-1$ for $x + 2y$. I was wondering how the line $x + 2y = -1$ had anything to do with this because you say $|x + 2y| < 1$ **or** $x + 2y = -1$, leading me into thinking somehow you related the two equation

Comment: @sizz Exactly. ${}$

Answer (score 1):

When you do the ratio test you evalute the limit of the absolute value hence you must consider this inequality $ |x+2y|<1$

Comment: Oh shoot, I forgot the absolute values. I did this on scratch paper  haha

Comment: @sizz ,btw what book do you use (just curious)

Comment: I actually got this problem from a GRE practice booklet